# What is the difference between GLES20.glTexImage2d() and GLUtils.texImage2d() in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture2d

I was trying to load a `bitmap` as a texture in `opengl` on Android platform. Although, I got it working by using

`GLUtils.texImage2d()`

but crashes when I use

`GLES20.glTexImage2d()`.

What is the difference between them? When to use the former and the latter?

Answer (score 1):

GLUtils.texImage2d() is an helper to load a texture from an Android Bitmap. GLES20.glTexImage2d() is the standard GL-ES function that load an image from a Java NIO Buffer. Prefer GLUtils function if you want to load images from files, it is much simple.